# Tags on Emacs.SE seem less useful than they could be

Tags: discussion, tags

I originally wrote this as a comment on the State of the Beta question, but decided to move it into its own thread once it got pretty long and detailed.

I have what I *think* is a problem, with no particular solutions in mind: **tags are not very useful** right now, compared to the other SE sites I use.

The core problem, as I see it, is that it's not clear what tags are *for*. Some are general topics like [key-bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings). Others describe a relevant core feature like [isearch](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isearch). Others describe an action you're taking, like [syntax-highlighting](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting). Others categorize by Emacs package ([org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-mode)) or external tool ([git](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git)). Then we have some special ones, like [emacs-24.4] for version-specific questions.

The problem is that these categories behave differently—often orthogonally. And the result is that we have a very long tail of tags with very few questions (5-15), which are mostly not very useful. Moreover, since there are so many different types of tags which can all apply to a single question, I suspect many questions are missing relevant tags, leading to even more fragmentation.

This makes tags more difficult to use for both asking *and* answering questions.

For asking, it's difficult to figure out which tags are necessary. Unless you're in one of a few very clear-cut cases ([org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-mode)), you have to guess something abstract—and since so many tags have a similarly small number of questions, it's hard to naturally tend towards the same tag other people are using. As it stands, there is no real pressure to consolidate on given tags, so the fragmentation problem isn't going to go away by itself.

On the flip side, as somebody who likes to answer questions, it's hard to find relevant ones. A lot of the more abstract tags don't work for me *at all*: seeing that a question is tagged [syntax-highlighting](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) doesn't tell me anything about what concrete knowledge is needed to answer it. More generally, I haven't found any good tags to follow, which is the main way I filter through to answerable questions on StackOverflow and Programmers.

As a concrete illustration of the problem, I've written 14 answers and 9 questions as of now, across 49 tags. Not a single one was ever repeated for more than one post, except for the one time when I answered my own question!

I think we need a holistic review of existing tags, with the aim to consolidate and pare them down enough to be more useful. But I don't have any ideas about how to do this that are specific enough for immediate action.

Answer (score 4):

### What I Disagree

I see where you're coming from, and I'm not agains a big discussion on
tags. But I'd like to offer a differing opinion.

- I subscribe to the [byte-compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/byte-compilation), [mode-line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mode-line), and
  [elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elisp) tags, and I never feel like I'm not getting what I paid
  for when those emails come in. The `elisp` tag suffers a bit of
  misuse, but that's not a problem with what the tag represents (it's
  a valid topic, it's just hard to avoid misuse (but I'm diverging,
  that's another meta topic)).
- Having a tail of 5-10 question tags doesn't sound terrible for a
  site barely approaching adulthood. It's the 1-4 tags that we might
  benefit from reviewing a bit (which is *not* to say we should kill
  them all, that's how tags are born).
- Having tags mean different things is not a problem either. SO has
  tags for languages, tools, methodologies. The only question we need
  to ask about tags is: *“Can somebody reasonably be expected to be an
  expert on it?”*

  For most tags you mentioned, the answer is yes. Git, org-mode,
  isearch, syntax-highlighting, are all deep topics where you could
  expect someone to consider him/herself as an expert. `key-bindings`
  is more complicated, the actual notion of a keybind is pretty
  simple, though the concept of a keymap is actually quite
  complicated, but this is also a topic of its own.

Answer (score 4):

### What I Agree

As I said on the other answer, I'm not agains a discussion on tags. In particular:

- You say tags are difficult to use for answering and asking, I'm very much interested to know if anyone else feels like that.
- We have a bit of a tag overload when it comes to programming
  languages. This has
  [been discussed before](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/50),
  and we went with the most logic answer, but I've been questioning
  myself whether that's the most effective one.

---

Some of the worries you mention are valid, but they seem more like
topics of their own then a single problem.

- [key-bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings) is somewhat useless. It's a perfectly relevant
  topic, and it even does say something about the question, but it
  doesn't help narrow the audience. Any Emacs.SE answerer worth his
  salt knows about `define-key`, and there's not much more to it.
  There's a lot of deep knowledge involved in [keymaps](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keymaps), but
  that's already a tag of its own.
- Anyone is invited to have a look at our tail and see if any tags can
  be merged at all. Just post a topic here on meta if you find any.
- Are there any specific cases where you found a question difficult to tag?

Comment: I looked at the tags and it seems that for programming language, the language tag like `python` is a better choice than the mode tag `python-mode` in fact there is _no_ `python-mode` tag. We can start to see inconsistencies when we look at the `haskell` tags, we have only `haskell-mode`. It is not intuitive at all. The case of `elpy` is an interesting one, I guess that `elpy` should always comes with `python` tag beside it. Same thing for `EDTS` and `erlang`...

Comment: ...  Tags are for experts but also for users and for users discoverability, so the language tag is the most important one and it should be coupled to whatever improves discoverability. Like discovering `elpy` for python users.

Comment: @syl20bnr Did you check out the linked discussion? That's sort of what we settled on (always use the language tag, and use the mode tag when appropriate). You're right it's not being used consistently yet.

Comment: yes I did and this is not the validated answer. The checked answer says that the tag of the mode and the tag of the language are 2 separate things. At least it is what the wording says: choose the apropriate tag. Here I say that the language is what it is the most important, python tag is then a better choice whatever the question is about the mode or/and the language. This is different than the checked answer. For the case of big modes with different naming than the language itself it is good to set both tags. But the language tag should _always_ be set.Same thing for git and magit

Answer (score 1):

The way Emacs "solves this" is with `apropos` and several different `apropos` flavours.  Would it be possible to write an `appropos-tags` (similar to `apropos-documentation`) would help people navigate the tag hierarchy, and pick fine-grained tags?

Another related possibility would be to require both general and specific tags, which is how ACM [goes about it](https://www.acm.org/about/class/2012) for the papers they publish.